# Grails 2.4.4 Criteria query issue, No such property: CriteriaSpecification for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder

Tags: grails, hibernate-criteria

I am using grails 2.4.4.

In my controller I am having the following line

```
 createAlias('someobject', 'so', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
```

Runtime error:

```
No such property: CriteriaSpecification for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
```

Do i have to import anything here?? No example or source showed any special imports.

Comment: found a solution, see below

Answer (score 3):

import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification;

solved it

Comment: I wanted to add that `CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN` is deprecated and you may want to update to `JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN`. You will need to add `import org.hibernate.sql.JoinType`
Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/CriteriaSpecification.html#LEFT_JOIN